# Algorithm for insight into string pattern matching

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis

My question is general but I struggle to find proper articles for that so any reading leads will be much appreciated!

I have two dataframes to join by Id that should be formed from multiple different columns. For example:

```
df.Id = df.A + df.B + df.C 
df2.Id= df2.A2 + df2.D2 + df2.E2 +df2.F2
```

There multiple cases when such simple column concatenation won't work to create matching Id and you cannot use multiple columns as key for merge because there are different number of them on both sides and they often have variable parts of Id.

To complete the task I had to manually find out and establish exception rules.
For example (if column df.A2 had a dash you would need to omit and other more convoluted):

```
df2.loc[df.A2.str.contains('-'),'Id'] = df2.D2 + df2.E2 +df2.F2
```

This got me thinking:

1. Are there ways I could speed up finding and/or visualizing such sub-populations (maybe something like clustering) ?
2. Are there algorithms that can aid into identifying those sub-population pattern divergencies (`if df2.A2 contains "-"`) and ways those divergencies can be fixed (`omit A2 to get a proper pattern`) ?

Comment: My best advice is normalize each, and then join.

Comment: What do you mean by "normalization"  Is it some from for string transformation ?

Comment: It means transforming things into some standardized form that can be depended on to match if the records should join.

Comment: I think it is exactly what I am doing (by finding incompatibilities and bringing all str to the same format) but there are so many different exceptions it is very hard to do by hand. How can I speed up this ?

Comment: There is no automated way to make inconsistent data consistent. Sorry. Figuring out how to structure and organize data is an intrinsically hard problem.

Comment: Hm, okey although I am not looking for automated data normalization but aid to find pattern discrepancy populations